# Producer-Consumer Implementation

Tags: linux, unix, semaphore

I need to implement producer-consumer problem in my project. N consumers and M producers will be created. A producer will use publish(v) call to reach v data to consumer. A consumer will use get_data(v) call to get a copy of data v. I really don't know how to implement it. Please help me.

I am going to use C to implement it. I will create n process for consumers and m process for producers. If a producer publish a data, other producers can not do it until all consumers get it. I will use semaphores and shared memory to exchange data.

I found something which does similar job. But it is using threads but i need process instead. How can i change this.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define BUFF_SIZE 4
#define FULL 0
#define EMPTY 0
char buffer[BUFF_SIZE];
int nextIn = 0;
int nextOut = 0;

sem_t empty_sem_mutex; //producer semaphore
sem_t full_sem_mutex; //consumer semaphore

void Put(char item)
{
int value;
sem_wait(&empty_sem_mutex); //get the mutex to fill the buffer

buffer[nextIn] = item;
nextIn = (nextIn + 1) % BUFF_SIZE;
printf("Producing %c ...nextIn %d..Ascii=%d\n",item,nextIn,item);
if(nextIn==FULL)
{
  sem_post(&full_sem_mutex);
  sleep(1);
}
sem_post(&empty_sem_mutex);

}

 void * Producer()
{
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  Put((char)('A'+ i % 26));
}
}

void Get()
{
int item;

sem_wait(&full_sem_mutex); // gain the mutex to consume from buffer

item = buffer[nextOut];
nextOut = (nextOut + 1) % BUFF_SIZE;
printf("\t...Consuming %c ...nextOut %d..Ascii=%d\n",item,nextOut,item);
if(nextOut==EMPTY) //its empty
{
  sleep(1);
}

sem_post(&full_sem_mutex);
}

void * Consumer()
{
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  Get();
}
}

int main()
{
  pthread_t ptid,ctid;
  //initialize the semaphores

  sem_init(&empty_sem_mutex,0,1);
  sem_init(&full_sem_mutex,0,0);

  //creating producer and consumer threads

   if(pthread_create(&ptid, NULL,Producer, NULL))
   {
  printf("\n ERROR creating thread 1");
  exit(1);
    }

 if(pthread_create(&ctid, NULL,Consumer, NULL))
  {
  printf("\n ERROR creating thread 2");
  exit(1);
   }

 if(pthread_join(ptid, NULL)) /* wait for the producer to finish */
  {
  printf("\n ERROR joining thread");
  exit(1);
  }

  if(pthread_join(ctid, NULL)) /* wait for consumer to finish */
   {
  printf("\n ERROR joining thread");
  exit(1);
}

  sem_destroy(&empty_sem_mutex);
  sem_destroy(&full_sem_mutex);

  //exit the main thread

    pthread_exit(NULL);
  return 1;
  }
```

Comment: Could you tell us the language, constraints to use (fork or thread, how to exchange the data via pipe/socket/shared memory, ...), etc.

Comment: I will use thread and shared memory to exchange data. And also they will work synchrounsly. I mean when the first producer publish a data second one can't do until all concumers get it.

Comment: I also know that this site is not a place to beg for code but i am really in a bad situtation. So any help will be life saver for me. Thank a lot.

Comment: will you have one producer process with M threads and one consumer process with N threads? What programming language should you use? Java, C, C++ or something else? Or do you need just pseudo code or general concept how to implement this?

Comment: If C: Are you allowed to call libraries outside the C standard (apart from the pthreads, which is required for doing threading with C in POSIX)?

Comment: I am going to use c and i can use all the linux system calls. And i will have m producer process and n concumer process together.

Comment: @eceçalıkuş - this still does not answer two things. 1. Like Huygens asked: "Or do you need just pseudo code or general concept how to implement this?" 2. Are you allowed to use libraries?

Comment: I need all the codes to implement this. And i can use libraries. I am sorry not to answer directly. I have trouble to explain in English. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: please update your question with the replies you've made in the  comments. Good luck.

Comment: Yes it is homework. I know it is not right to ask you to help my homework directly. But i am stuck. I have very few time to finish and it is just the way to begin the project. Otherwise i am not going to continue

Comment: I don't have the experience you need, but recommend that you try some google searchs OR better yet search here on StackOverflow, as I see this sort of problem discussed pretty regularly. Good luck.

Comment: Actually you don't have to write creating process or other things like that. I just need how to write publish(v) and get_data(v) methods using shared memory.

Comment: Your lecture notes or textbook should probably provide you with pseudo code that solves the problem. If you have a specific question about implementing that pseudocode in C, feel free to ask, but please state where you're stuck and what you've already tried (including a code sample). We won't solve your complete homework for you.

Comment: I could have helped you with Java threads API or C fork API, but not pthreads... Also I'm a bit puzzled why you would use shared memory for a multi-threaded program. This is an unnecessary burden as the process own memory is shared among the threads. Shared memory is for forked processes.

Comment: @Huygens I have asked after your question. We are allowed to use both ways

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you to make a plan and start reading. For example:

1. Read about how to create and manage threads. Hint: pthread.
2. Think how will the threads communicate - usually they use common data structure. Hint: message queue
3. Think how to protect the data structure, so both threads can read and write safely. Hint: mutexes.
4. Implement consumer and producer code.

Really, if you want more information you have to work a bit and ask more specific questions. Good luck!